# How can I disable select option based on another select option

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have two tables `gender` and `names`
the names table have list of : 
- males names from nameID 1 to nameID 10 
- female names from nameID 11 to nameID 21 
- both from nameID 23 to nameID 31

the gender table have three attribute:
- female 
- male
- both

I'm using bootstrap select option I want to display the names from nameID11 to nameID 21 if the user select female from the gender select option and so on
is this possible to do 
I saw other posts and I noticed that they use javascript I've never used javascript before can I achieve the same result with another method

tableGender
................... 
genderID (PK)
genderName *it can be male , female or both*

tableNames
................... 
nameID (PK)
name

```
 <?php
include "connection.php";

echo " <p> Gender </p>";
echo "<select class='form-control' name='gender'>";
echo "'<option value=''></option>";

$sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tableGender");

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)) {



    echo '<option selected="selected"  value="' . $row2['genderID'] . '">' . $row2['genderName'] . "</option>";





}

echo "</select>";


echo " <p> Names </p>";
echo "<select class='form-control' name='name'>";
echo "'<option value=''></option>";

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tableNames");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {



    echo '<option selected="selected"  value="' . $row['nameID'] . '">' . $row['name'] . "</option>";





}

echo "</select>";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to show only select-options what you want.
Code is not tested!

```
$("input[name=gender]").change(function() {
    var gender = this.value;
    $("input[name=name] option").each(function() {
        if ((gender == "your-male-id" && this.value >= 1 && this.value <= 10) ||
            (gender == "your-female-id" && this.value >= 11 && this.value <= 20) ||
            (gender == "your-both-id" && this.value >= 21 && this.value <= 30)
        ) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
})
```